# (Invalid asm.js: Invalid member of stdlib) while trying to compile solidity 0.4.17

Tags: node.js, ethereum, solidity, web3js

> (Invalid asm.js: Invalid member of stdlib) while trying to compile solidity 0.4.17

> (Invalid asm.js: Invalid member of stdlib) while trying to compile solidity 0.4.17

> (Invalid asm.js: Invalid member of stdlib) while trying to compile solidity 0.4.17

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs-extra');
const solc = require('solc');

const buildPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'build');
fs.removeSync(buildPath);


const contractPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'contracts', 'Campaign.sol');
const source = fs.readFileSync(contractPath, 'utf8');

const output = solc.compile(source, 1).contracts;


fs.ensureDirSync(buildPath);


for (let contract in output) {
    fs.outputJsonSync(
        path.resolve(buildPath, contract.replace(':', '') + '.json'),
        output[contract]
    );
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue, what solved it for me was changing version of the solidity compiler. I picked it arbitrarily tbh, and worked.
I typed in the console:

```
npm install solc@0.4.26
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be hitting the same problem that affects the 0.4.25 binary: [asm.js build of soljson 0.4.25 fails on node.js 14+ #537](https://github.com/ethereum/solc-js/issues/537).

Unfortunately I don't know what is the cause but if it's the same problem then simply downloading the wasm binary will solve it: [`emscripten-wasm32/solc-emscripten-wasm32-v0.4.17+commit.bdeb9e52.js`](https://binaries.soliditylang.org/emscripten-wasm32/solc-emscripten-wasm32-v0.4.17+commit.bdeb9e52.js).

The wasm binaries should also be faster than the asm.js ones so I recommend always using them.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is there is no contract result in output(const of solc compiler).